# Example: Mono's DataContractJsonSerializer won't serialize, but .NET will

Tags: c#, macos, serialization, mono, xamarin

This is a program that is ready to run in Xamarin and VS2013.

I'm having an issue where mono isn't calling the serializer Subclass, and need to work around that issue.

**Question**

How should I modify SetMembershipProof so that it will call a method with the attribute [OnSerializing] located in a nested subclass of ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MonoBug
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SetMembershipProof2 setMembershipProof = new SetMembershipProof2();
            string setProofJSON =    CryptoSerializer.Serialize<SetMembershipProof2>(setMembershipProof);
           // Inspect the contents of SetProofJSON, it is null under mono, and not null in .NET
        }
    }
    public class CryptoSerializer
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Serialize serializable types in namespace UProveCrypto.PolyProof.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">input type</typeparam>
        /// <param name="obj">instance of serializable type</param>
        /// <returns>JSON string</returns>
        public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
        {
            string result;

            try
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer =
                        new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());

                    jsonSerializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
                    ms.Position = 0;

                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms);
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new SerializationException(obj.GetType().Name, e);
            }

            return result;
        }



    }
    [DataContract]
    public abstract class GroupParameterizedSerializer2
    {

        [OnSerializing]
        public void SerializeGroup(StreamingContext context)
        {


        }

    }
    [DataContract]
    public class SetMembershipProof2 : GroupParameterizedSerializer2
    {
        #region Serialization

        /// <summary>
        /// Serialization of a
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember(Name = "a", EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 2)]
        internal string[] _a;

        /// <summary>
        /// Serialization of c
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember(Name = "c", EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 3)]
        internal string[] _c;

        /// <summary>
        /// Serialization of r
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember(Name = "r", EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 4)]
        internal string[] _r;

        /// <summary>
        /// Serialize a, c, r.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">The streaming context.</param>
        [OnSerializing]
        internal void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Debug: This isn't called in Mono...");

            List<string> t = new List<string>();
            t.Add("data1");
            _a = t.ToArray();

            t.Clear();
            t.Add("data2");
            _c = t.ToArray();

            t.Clear();
            t.Add("data3");
            _r = t.ToArray();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your serializer to:

```
internal string GetJson<T>(T obj)
{
...
DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer =
                        new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
...
}
```

Depending on with how you call `GetJson<T>`, `typeof(T)` might return the superclass of the serialized object `obj`.  On the other hand, `obj.GetType()` always returns the specific class of the object that is being serialized.  This may be why the `[OnSerializing]` methods of the subclasses are not being called in Mono.

Comment: Mono still fails at deserializing this.