# Does Protobuf.NET process [OnSerializing]? "Non-public member cannot be used with full dll compilation"

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, protobuf-net, portable-class-library

I'm trying to [port a project](https://uprovecsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#UProveCrypto/UProveCrypto/Issuer.cs) from .NET to a Portable Class Library for use with iOS and Android, and am having [Mono serialization issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26953606/328397) with DataContractJsonSerializer, so I'm replacing that with Protobuf.

I see a lot of questions about Protobuf, and some old documentation on MonoTouch, so it's possible/likely I'm doing something wrong. (please correct me if so)

The following is my failed attempt at swapping out and replacing DataContractJsonSerializer with ProtoBuf.net.

> The error is that `OnSeralizing` is actually public, has no external dependencies, but still won't precompile

**Protobuf source**

I'm using the [latest pull from Github](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net).

**PCL configuration:**

The DTO is referencing [Protobuf.NET_Portable](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/tree/master/protobuf-net_Portable)

I'm using [Profile 344](http://danrigby.com/2014/05/14/supported-pcl-profiles-xamarin-for-visual-studio-2/) in my DTO

**Sample DTO**

This "DTO" is what this exact code is what I'm trying to use with protobuf.  It is representative of the crazy class I'm porting. (Very complex).   I put "DTO" in quotes because the objects are very messy & complicated, and would take a very long time to simplify & optimize.

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;

namespace MonoBug
{
    [ProtoContract]
    [DataContract]
    public abstract class GroupParameterizedSerializer2
    {

        [OnSerializing]
        public void SerializeGroup(StreamingContext context)
        {


        }

    }
    [ProtoContract]
    [DataContract]
    public class SetMembershipProof2 : GroupParameterizedSerializer2
    {
        #region Serialization

        /// <summary>
        /// Serialization of a
        /// </summary>
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        [DataMember(Name = "a", EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 2)]
        public string[] _a;

        /// <summary>
        /// Serialization of c
        /// </summary>
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        [DataMember(Name = "c", EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 3)]
        public string[] _c;

        /// <summary>
        /// Serialization of r
        /// </summary>
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        [DataMember(Name = "r", EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 4)]
        public string[] _r;

        /// <summary>
        /// Serialize a, c, r.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">The streaming context.</param>
        [OnSerializing]
        public void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
        {

            // This is a simluation ... 
            // existing code expects to perform calculations then proceed with serialization 
            List<string> t = new List<string>();
            t.Add("data1");
            _a = t.ToArray();

            t.Clear();
            t.Add("data2");
            _c = t.ToArray();

            t.Clear();
            t.Add("data3");
            _r = t.ToArray();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
Y:\DevUtil\Protobuf>precompile "\\psf\Home\Desktop\MonoBug\Types\bin\Debug\types
.dll" -o:PortableTypes.dll -t:MonoBug
protobuf-net pre-compiler
Detected framework: .NETPortable\v4.0\Profile\Profile344
Resolved C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPor
table\v4.0\Profile\Profile344\mscorlib.dll
Resolved C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPor
table\v4.0\Profile\Profile344\System.dll
Resolved \\psf\Home\Desktop\MonoBug\Types\bin\Debug\protobuf-net.dll
Resolved C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPor
table\v4.0\Profile\Profile344\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
Adding MonoBug.GroupParameterizedSerializer2...
Adding MonoBug.SetMembershipProof2...
Compiling MonoBug to PortableTypes.dll...
Non-public member cannot be used with full dll compilation: MonoBug.SetMembershi
pProof2.OnSerializing

 ^^^^^^^^ 

   at ProtoBuf.Compiler.CompilerContext.CheckAccessibility(MemberInfo member) in
 \\psf\home\Documents\Git\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Compiler\CompilerContext.cs:
line 815
   at ProtoBuf.Compiler.CompilerContext.EmitCall(MethodInfo method) in \\psf\hom
e\Documents\Git\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Compiler\CompilerContext.cs:line 558
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.TypeSerializer.EmitInvokeCallback(CompilerContext ctx
, MethodInfo method, Boolean copyValue, Type constructType, Type type) in \\psf\
home\Documents\Git\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\TypeSerializer.cs:line
466
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.TypeSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoTypeSeriali
zer.EmitCallback(CompilerContext ctx, Local valueFrom, CallbackType callbackType
) in \\psf\home\Documents\Git\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\TypeSerializ
er.cs:line 511
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.TypeSerializer.EmitCallbackIfNeeded(CompilerContext c
tx, Local valueFrom, CallbackType callbackType) in \\psf\home\Documents\Git\prot
obuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\TypeSerializer.cs:line 485
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.TypeSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.
EmitWrite(CompilerContext ctx, Local valueFrom) in \\psf\home\Documents\Git\prot
obuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializers\TypeSerializer.cs:line 343
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.WriteSerializers(CompilerOptions options, S
tring assemblyName, TypeBuilder type, Int32& index, Boolean& hasInheritance, Ser
ializerPair[]& methodPairs, ILVersion& ilVersion) in \\psf\home\Documents\Git\pr
otobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 1516
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Compile(CompilerOptions options) in \\psf\h
ome\Documents\Git\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 1132
   at ProtoBuf.Precompile.PreCompileContext.Execute() in \\psf\home\Documents\Gi
t\protobuf-net\precompile\Program.cs:line 433
   at ProtoBuf.Precompile.Program.Main(String[] args) in \\psf\home\Documents\Gi
t\protobuf-net\precompile\Program.cs:line 32
```

Comment: `OnSeralizing` is used by some serializers like BinaryFormatter and SoapFormatter, but I don't think it is a common interface to use by all serializers like ProtoBuf (every serializer has its own tricks)

Comment: Perhaps the error is saying that "full DLL compilation" requires no dynamic or pre-computation.. Perhaps the regular reflection method is the only way in my case.

Comment: Perhaps you should try and see..

Comment: I just tried regular Protobuf at runtime and got a strange error about the method signature being incorrect.  I also tried JSON.NET and that worked for this sample, so I'll proceed with that less-than-ideal situation until I get something better (protobuf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a bug. The method is clearly `public` - it could be that the "this isn't going to work" detection is simply making a mistake in this case. That looks fine. I'll try to have a look later today (I only have my 'phone right now).

And yes: protobuf-net does recognise and use `[OnSerializing]`